# Horizontall scroll in react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, next.js13, react-virtualized

I am new to next.js , currently I am looking to design an UI which I have mentioned below in an image
[UI that I want to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1N4Z.png) .
[image]
I am struck on how to implement this UI using react virtualized , is it possible to build this UI using react-virtualized in horizontal view along with that left and right arrows. Also I need to know is there any option for callback while scrolling to the end of the horizontal view so that I can make an API call and merge new set of data for react-virtualized.
Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.